# AsyncTask- how to funnel an async call with no result callback

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

---

The activity below has 2 async tasks running in parallel.
  The question is :  when the 'bar' AsyncTask   is run, the activity member     calls its method myExec.startSomething() and is run in the background.  It triggers a callback based on success or failure, and the listener methods are implemented in the activity class.  How do I funnel the listener callback result to the activity class because it is running in a separate thread? 
Eg:  listener.onFail() is called rather than onSomething().  I have all the listener methods in the activity.  I need to funnel along the callback.

thanks
~

---

```
public class MyExecutor {


 public void startSomething() {
    listener.doSomething();
 }
```

}

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements FooListener {

private MyExecutor myExec;
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myExec = mApp.getProvisionExecutor();
    myExec.addListener(this);
 ...
   }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();

   if (myExec.isSomethingorOther() ) {

        (bar = new AsyncTask<Void, String, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                myExec.startSomething(null);
                ---->>>>>//startSomething triggers onSomething callback
                 ------>>> in myExecutor class
                return null;

            }
        }).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);
    }

    if (!foobar && isReady()) {


        (new AsyncTask<Void, String, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return SomethingGood());
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                if (null != result) {
                    poncho.setColor(result);
                }

               ...
            }

        }).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);

}

//listener methods 
@Override
public void onSomething() {
  //am I reached this way or do I need to pass back a callback result
  doSomethingGreat();

}
....
private void doSomethingGreat() {
 //
 }

 ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be on the UI thread when the bar thread stops, implement that in onPostExecute().